# como crear un rectangulo con el mouse en c#

Tags: c#

he intentado crear un código en [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) para crear un rectángulo con el mouse pero no me ha funcionado.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { }



        private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            using (Graphics g = this.panel1.CreateGraphics())
            {
                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
                Brush brush = new SolidBrush(this.panel1.BackColor);

                g.FillRectangle(brush, this.panel1.Bounds);  
                g.DrawRectangle(pen, e.X, e.Y, 20, 20);

                pen.Dispose();
                brush.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private Panel panel1;

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.SuspendLayout();

            this.panel1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Cross;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-2, -2);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(676, 429);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.panel1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.panel1_Paint);
            this.panel1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.panel1_MouseDown);

            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(674, 424);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Cross;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "rectangles";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load_1);
            this.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.panel1_MouseDown);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hola, hay una respuesta parecida a lo que pides en http://stackoverflow.com/a/6060658/2026740, revisala

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private int x = -1;
        private int y = -1;

        private Rectangle rect;
        private bool pintar = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;

            pintar = true;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (pintar)
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(Math.Min(e.X, x),
                                Math.Min(e.Y, y),
                                (e.X - y),
                                (e.Y - y));

                panel1.Invalidate();
                panel1.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            pintar = false;

            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (Graphics g = this.panel1.CreateGraphics())
            {
                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);

                g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);

                pen.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```